# Google tag manager. Fire e-commerce transaction fails

Tags: google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Why does the below transaction doesn't appear in Google Analytics?

```
dataLayer = [{
    'transactionId': '1234',
    'transactionAffiliation': 'TEST AFFILATION',
    'transactionTotal': 38.26,
    'transactionTax': 1.29,
    'transactionShipping': 5,
    'transactionProducts': [{
        'sku': 'DD44',
        'name': 'TEST',
        'category': 'TESTCATEGORY',
        'price': 0.00,
        'quantity': 1
    },{
        'sku': 'AA1243544',
        'name': 'Test1',
        'category': 'TESTCAT',
        'price': 0.00,
        'quantity': 2
    }]
}];</script>

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
 google tagmanager script here
```

Comment: How have you configured GTM to read this dataLayer?  Can you add that?

Comment: This is probably something that I miss. How can this be done please?

Comment: I'll google this of course

Comment: Oh, I think you mean declaration of dataLayer name. It is default, my tagmanager script has this (sorry, I cannot publish whole tag here): })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>

Comment: Did you create a transaction tag to fire as well?

Comment: @nyuen. We didn't clearly understand that bit from ga documentation. In short, we didn't create any tag. Even when we did create it then I don't understand how we "fire" it. Finally we decided, that you create a tag if you want to fire it by setting up trigger event in GTM. In our case we want to create dataLayer object dynamically and fire it from our code. hope it makes sense

Comment: What nyuen is saying is, you need to create a Google Analytics tag and set the tracking type to transaction, then set a trigger that shows the tag on your order confirmation page. The transaction tag will pick up the dataLayer automatically,but it will not fire all by itself.

Comment: As said above, after you deploy the dataLayer/GTM script you need to log in to GTM and configure your tags that will be served, in your case at least GA trasaction tag.